# Why does my authentication middleware pass a request to the authorization filter when no token is supplied?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 1.1 Web API which uses JWT authentication middleware and a custom authorization filter.  They are defined like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationRequirement, MercuryEndpointAuthorizationHandler>();
services.AddSingleton<IEndpointAuthorizeDictionary, EndpointRights>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MercuryEndpointAuthorizationHandler>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AuthorizeMercuryEndpoint", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddRequirements(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAuthorizationRequirement>());
    });
});
```

and

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = async (context) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("====>  JWT Message received");
        },
        OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("====>  JWT token validated");
            context.HttpContext.Items["JwtTokenIsValid"] = true;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = async (context) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("====>  JWT token failed auth");
            context.HttpContext.Items["JwtTokenIsValid"] = false;
            if ((AuthenticationType.IdServer & authTypes) != 0)
                context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
        }
    }
});
```

When I call an endpoint protected with `[Authorize("AuthorizeMercuryEndpoint")]` and a valid JWT token, the call succeeds as expected, and I see the following debug written by the process:

```
====>  JWT Message received
====>  JWT token validated
====>  Request authorized (when the auth filter succeeds)
```

However, if I do not pass a token, the JWT middleware appears to pass the request straight to the authorization filter without attempting authentication - neither `OnTokenValidated` nor `OnAuthenticationFailed` are called, and when authorization fails (because there is no authenticated identity) the pipeline is terminated.

This is a problem because I want to pass the request to a second authentication middleware if the JWT token validation fails the initial authentication.

Does anyone know what the recommended approach for this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JWT middleware does apply the validation part only if it finds a token in the HTTP request, as you can [see here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/c64c5db02dea6e793d2fad564c094a219618cece/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L50-L67).

The `Authorize` attribute now contains an `ActiveAuthenticationSchemes` property which defines which authentication schemes will be executed to try to authenticate the user. The advantage of that is you can now remove the `AutomaticAuthenticate` in the JWT middleware options, and it will be executed lazily when needed - like, if the user hits an action that doesn't require authentication, it will not execute.

One thing you might not like, though, is that MVC won't stop after an authentication scheme was successful, as you can [see here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L128-L139). If that's a trade-off you're willing to take, I think it's a good way to go.

Comment: Great answer, good to see the code, thanks.  Your last comment - do you mean that, if I have >1 authentication method configured, they will be invoked one after the other regardless of whether one succeeds or not?  If so I have dealt with this by adding a value to `context.HttpContext.Items` which subsequent authentication can use to skip if authentication has previously succeeded - sound like the right solution?

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Regarding your question, yes, MVC will invoke all your authentication schemes and won't stop as soon as one is successful. I may not have the full picture, but do you **really** need to stop when one authentication scheme succeeds?

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey you mention "Authenticate... will be executed lazily when needed", do you know how can force NETCore2 to execute always. Question is related with problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685448/netcore2-how-to-populate-user-without-setting-authorize-attribute-in-controller